# Difference between <image:caption> and html alt=""

Tags: html, seo, sitemap, caption, alt

In my sitemap an image tag has the following structure:

```
<url>
  <loc>?</loc>
  <image:image>
    <image:loc>?.jpg</image:loc>
    <image:title>?</image:title>
    <image:caption>?</image:caption>
    <image:geo_location>?</image:geo_location>
    <image:license>?</image:license>
  </image:image>
</url>
```

Meanwhile HTML has :

```
<img  src='images/blah.jpg' alt="altText">
```

My question is:
When I use the sitemap's `<image:caption>?</image:caption>` do I need to use the same text from the HTML tag's alt field? Like so: `<image:caption>altText</image:caption>`

Do they both need to be the same text OR I can use different texts on both
**caption** and **alt** ?

Is there a penalty if I use duplicate texts for the sitemap and for the alt text of the image?

Please someone to clarify this.
Thanks.

Comment: This question is not on topic as defined in [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If you don't understand why, please ask on [meta] for help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for SEO advice (whether or not something gives a penalty). It might be on-topic on [webmasters.se].